# Silverlight Data Binding in Nested Controls

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

Hi guys I am working with SL4 and MVVM application actually i am stuck some where i might be doing some thing wrong thats why need your help, here is my scenario

```
//suodo code 
public class EmployeeModel
{
    //code
    Public List<Shifts> Employeeshifts{get;set;}
}

public class ShiftModel
{
    //code
}
```

Viewmodel for main page

```
public class MainVM
{
    MainVM()
    {
        EmployeeList = DateFromSomeService;
    }
    Public List<Employees> EmployeeList{get;set}
    Public DelegateCommand ClickBindingCommand{get;set;} 
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource={Binding EmployeeList}>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:EmployeeControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Employeecontro.xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource={Binding EmployeeShifts}>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:ShiftControl  Click={Binding ClickBindingCommand}/>//here is problem this command is in mainviewmodel
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MainPage.cs

```
this.DataContext = new MainVM();
```

`ClickBindingCommand` is defined in main VM but it is bound within shift control and shiftcontrol's data context is shift class which is my model class. If I declare this command in my shift model class than it works, means if I click on shift control this property is called but I dont want this because I want it in my main view model, where am I wrong?

Should I declare it in my shift model class but in this way i will bind directly my model to my view?

Comment: Please update your question title to something more relevant to your problem - it's currently just a list of tags, which belong in the 'tags' section.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) or a [RelativeSource](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/) Binding.  This will allow your Command to bind/fire on your MainViewModel.

Another alternative is to use the [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) framework.  You can then attach an action to your button in the child and click events will bubble up to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This "toolkit" offers an implementation of FindAncestor in silverlight. Try this:

http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and what fixed it for me was to name my UserControl then reference that name in the binding.

Here is the syntax:

**{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox, Path=Text}**

**Bind to the “Text” property of the element XAML 
element with name=”SomeTextBox” or x:Name=”SomeTextBox”.**

So here is my user control:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"             
             x:Class="SupportReports.Workflow.Portfolio.PortfolioManager"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="PortfolioManagerControl"
             >
```

And here is the nested dataTemplate that binds to my command in my main view model

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=PortfolioManagerControl, Path=DataContext.PortfolioManagerProjectSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=ProjectName}" />
```